# Recreate map in bloc pattern every time receive new location

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am trying to use [bloc pattern](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) in map application. Application when is started, user location is found first and then change the map center to user location.
When user moved i want to change marker on the map.This is my code:

```
class HomeFoursquareScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<LocationBloc, LocationState>(
      builder: (context, locationState) {
        if (locationState is LocationLoadingState) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (locationState is LocationLoadedState) {
          return _MyMap(locationState.location);
        } else {
          return const Text('oops...something went wrong');
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class _MyMap extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MyMap({Key key, @required this.location}) : super(key: key);

  final Location location;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<FourSquareBloc, FourSquareState>(
      builder: (context, foursquareState) {
        return FlutterMap(...);
      }
    );
  },
)
```

But as you can see in my code every time my location is changed, that's mean when user is moving `LocationLoadedState` is triggered and `_MyMap` widget is called and `FlutterMap` is recreated !! I think it is not good for performance and it is not logical to create new instance of map continuously ! Is it right ? And What is right way?

I want to be fixed map but other thing like MapOptions or Marker get data when new data arrived.

Comment: What about an InheritedWidget / Provider.of approach?

Comment: What is related of to bloc or my problem? @GeorgeLee